# How to call the user control method in the page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have the Following method in Usercontrol.ascx

```
public void Flasmessage()
{
    popupmessage2.Visible = true;
    string strScript = "HideCtrl('" + popupmessage2.ClientID + "','15000')";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
      this.GetType(),
      Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
      strScript,
      true);
}
```

I need the following method to be called from another Page  and another Usercontrol.ascx

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a reference to the instance of the UserControl on your page, then call the method, like so:

```
void Page_Load() {

    // do this if your control does not exist in your *.aspx file and needs to be manually added:
    MyUserControl control = (MyUserControl)LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx");
    this.Controls.Add( control );

    // do this if your control already exists in your page as a named control
    MyUserControl control = (MyUserControl)FindControl("myUserControl");

    // do this in both cases, or if your UserControl exists as a field in your *.aspx-generated page class.
    control.MyMethod();

}
```

Comment: var control = (HeaderAfterLoggingIn)FindControl("HeaderAfterLoggingIn");
                            control.Flashmessage("Message Successfullysaved")...I used your method..My method in the user control did not invoked...

Comment: Do i use UserControl or MyuserControl.I mean where is this Myusercontrol defined? I am not able to access the method of usercontrol with this method.

Comment: @user35 `MyUserControl` is the name of the (superclass) class/type that your UserControl is defined as inheriting from. If you're not using a precompiled application (e.g. ASP.NET Websites rather than ASP.NET Applications) then you must use `Control` instead of whatever your subclass is.

Comment: @Dai my usercontrol file name is lcont which is inside the usercontrol folder.I am trying to access my usercontrol by the above method in a aspx page but i am not able to do so.Help he!

Answer (score -1):

Make the method public inside the UserControl, like:

```
public int Calculate()
{

}
```

And then in page call it as following

```
int total = MyControl.Calculate();
```

Comment: What is this..I cant undersatnd it